# What does "Mopsschnarchlaute" mean?

Tags: translation, meaning, german-to-english

The scentence is:

> Auf der anderen Seite des Sofas lag Kommissar Toby und stieß leise Mopsschnarchlaute aus

I cannot find any results in any dictionary or from search engines.

How should I break up this type of word to translate it?

Can you show the steps you took in order to work out the translation of the word?

Comment: And did you find "Mops"? If so, you could suspect it to be a composition, and search for S/schnachlaute.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In German composite substantives the thing that's actually described is always found at the end (the composite generally resolves from right to left) - *Laute*, plural of *Laut* - i.e. **sounds**

*schnarch* comes next, i.e. **snoring** - So we are talking about the sound someone makes when snoring.

And the *Mops*, at last, is a *pug dog*

> Mopsschnarchlaute

thus translates to

> the sounds of a pug snoring

Comment: Als Fremdsprachler weiß man aber nicht wo die Wortgrenzen liegen und muss daher von links anfangen, also mit Mops... und dann den Rest ergründen.

Comment: @userunknown Irgendwie will mir nicht einleuchten, dass man die Wortgrenzen als Fremdsprachler nur von links nach rechts finden kann.

Comment: Nicht nur, aber besser. Gerade bei 3 Teilen, wie hier, kann es natürlich sein, dass jmd. "Laute" identifizieren kann. Aber wenn man mit Hilfe eines Wörtterbuchs vorgeht, dann wird man eher links beginnen, und nach Mops suchen, und dann schauen, ob es Mopsschnarach gibt. Hiier sind alle 3 Teile jeweils einsilbig, ausser dem "Laute" am Ende. Soll man nach E, Te, Ute, Aute suchen, wenn man es nicht weiß - das ist jeweils mit neuem Blättern verbunden. Also beginnt man besser links. Allerdings schließt das Mehrdeutigkeiten nicht aus und man bekommt Schhwierigkeiten mit Fugenlauten

Comment: @userunknown Du scheinst von *überhaupt keinen* Deutschkenntnissen auszugehen. Da mag das schon so sein, jemand, der die Vokabeln "Laut", "schnarchen" und "Mops" schon kennt, muss aber kein Muttersprachler sein...

Comment: Wer die 3 Vokabeln schon kennt, der kennt auch Komposita und kann dieses ganz ohne Wörterbuch erkennen.

Comment: @userunknown ...und wenn nicht, liest er bestimmt ein deutsches Buch? *Verstehen* kann man es besser, wenn man mit den "Lauten" anfängt - das ist nämlich, was der Kommissar ausstößt

Comment: Auch eine Zupfinstrumentenfabrik stößt Lauten aus, Um das Geschlecht zu bestimmen fängt man rechts an, und was es grob gesehen ist, hängt meist am letzten Wort, Versuch Deine Methode doch mal mit Holzblasinstrumenten oder mit Putengeschnetzeltes. Vorwissen: Zelt, Netz, ...

Comment: @userunknown Dass der Komissar keine Zupfinstrumentenfabrik ist, dürfte dem Leser schon auffallen..